# MYSQL count listings for each user where listing published in past

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a MYSQL query that I am having difficulties getting to do what I want.

I have a users table (userstbl) containing all my user records, and a listings table (listings) contains all listings posted by each user.  I am trying to select the name and address of each user and provide a count of listings for each user which was listed between a certain date range, but only count adverts for unique category_id's which is working fine.
The issue is that I only want to count listings that have been published.  I have another table which is identical to my listings table called "listings_log" and contains a record for every change made to every listing record.  If one of the records in "listings_log" for the listing has a "listings_log.published=1" than the listing was published. Each record in the "listings_log" table has a "listing_id" which is the same as in the "listings" table.

This is the query I have now :

```
SELECT
  userstbl.userid,
  userstbl.fullname, 
  userstbl.fulladdress, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(
    CASE WHEN listings.ad_type = 1 
    AND DATE(listings.date_listed) BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-01'
    THEN listings.category_id
    END )
  ) AS Listings_Count_2018,
  DATE_FORMAT(userstbl.reg_date, "%d/%m/%Y") AS RegisteredDate
FROM
  users
LEFT JOIN listings ON listings.userid = userstbl.user_id
GROUP BY userstbl.userid
```

This counts the number of unique listings records between the correct dates for each user.

But I somehow only need to count listings records, where there is a corresponding listings_log record for that listing with published set to "1".  The "listings_log" table and "listings"  table both have a common listing_id column, but the listings_log table can have multiple records for each listing showing every change to each listing.

So I want to also join on the listings_log.listing_id = listings.listing_id and at least one of the "listings_log" records for that "listing_id" has listings_log.published = "1".

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide sample tables and a minimal reproducible example, a lot of this is guesswork. I am assuming for each user you want the total number of listing records. I built up the SQL with subqueries that are meant to be read "from the inside out."

```
select u.userid, u.fullname, u.fulladdress, sq.count from usertbl u join (
    select u.userid, sum(c.count) as count from usertbl u join (
        select count(*) as count, l.userid, l.listing_id from listings l join (
           select distinct listing_id from listings_log where listings_log.published = "1"
        ) ll on l.listing_id = ll.listing_id
             and l.ad_type = 1
             and date(l.date_listed) between '2018-01-01' and '2018-04-01'
        group by l.userid, l.listing_id
     ) c on u.userid = c.userid
    group by u.userid
) sq on u.userid = sq.userid
;
```

[See DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nZoeGHbeVtntXZKZwwWQ2o/0)